# How to programmatically load a View?

Tags: 8, views

I have created a View that I want to fetch the output from within a module.
On drupal.org, the latest [recommendation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api#s-load) seems to be

`$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load(1)`

So, this is my code.

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager */
$view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('view')
  ->load($view_id);
$view->getDisplay('latest_blog');
```

It seems to be getting me very close - in debug, I'm seeing properties that clearly indicate I'm getting the object.

Am I on the right track and just missing one little piece? Loading a taxonomy term, or a node is easy. But this View thing is stumping me and I can't find anything much beyond the old Drupal 7 way of doing this.

Comment: Getting the output of an entity is probably rendering the entity. Generally, *loading* is used to only mean *fetching an entity from its storage*.

Comment: @LesLim I disagree... A search for that (which I did, incidentally) will show how to "render" the view. That is not what I want. 
The answer using the same context yields the results I would expect for a node. The same, it seems, should apply to a View.

Comment: Then I suppose I'm not sure what you're expecting to see on the loaded entity, that you're not seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @4x4.  I dug around core and also found that.
My working code that produces the resulting node from the query is this.

```
  $view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('view')
    ->load($view_id)
    ->getExecutable();

  // Get the NID from the View result.
  $view->initDisplay();
  $view->setDisplay('latest_blog');
  $view->execute();
  $result = $view->result;
```

With the NID from that, we can easily get the path - which was what I needed.

Comment: If you just wanted to the result, a little shortcut [views_get_view_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_get_view_result/9.3.x)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to load a [ViewExecutable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/9.2.x):

> class ViewExecutable
>
> Represents a view as a whole.
>
> An object to contain all of the data to generate a view, plus the
> member functions to build the view query, execute the query and render
> the output.

```
$executable = $view->getExecutable();
```